# Manipulating skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Consider the following object $$M_{ij} = A_{il}B_{lj}-A_{jl}B_{li}$$ where repeated indicies imply summation and $A$ and $B$ are invertible anti-symmetric matrices. Now, clearly, $M$ is anti-symmetric (skew) in the index $i, j$. Now, I wish to isolate an instance of $A$ and for that I make use of inverses to write

$$A_{ik} = M_{ij}B^{-1}_{jk}-B^{-1}_{kj}A_{jl}B_{li}$$

Now, $A$ is an anti-symmetric matrix, however, the RHS of the above equation is not manifestly anti-symmetric and I doubt if it is even anti-symmetric. Can someone suggest a way to write $A$ in a manifestly anti-symmetric way or point out any errors in my manipulation?

Comment: Your last equation says that $A = MB^{-1} - B^{-1}AB$, but the correct statement would be $A = MB^{-1} + BAB^{-1}$. However, this is still not manifestly skew-symmetric. On the right-hand side, if you take generic $A$ then this expression will not be skew-symmetric.

Comment: @Nick I was kind of hoping that I must have made a grievous error in my manipulation to not lead to a manifestly skew-symmetric answer. Are you sure there aren't anymore errors in my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify by making a small change to the notation.
Let $A_{ij} := A^i_j$ and let matrix multiplication take place by only bottom-top contraction *i.e.* $(AB)^i_j = A^i_kB^k_j$.

This means that we now have the following facts,
$$M^i_j = A^i_kB^k_j - B^i_kA^k_j$$
and
$$A^i_j = -A^j_i, \qquad B^i_j = -B^j_i$$

Now we can separate out $A^i_j$ in 2 different ways,
\begin{align}
A^i_kB^k_j &= M^i_j + B^i_kA^k_j\\
A^i_kB^k_j (B^{-1})^j_l &= M^i_j(B^{-1})^j_l + B^i_kA^k_j(B^{-1})^j_l\\
A^i_l &= M^i_j(B^{-1})^j_l + B^i_kA^k_j(B^{-1})^j_l \tag{1}
\end{align}
similarly we can have (from the $B^i_kA^k_j$ term)
\begin{equation}
A^i_l = (B^{-1})^i_jA^j_kB^k_l - (B^{-1})^i_jM^j_l \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Let us test the anti-symmetry of eq. (1). Note that the inverse of an anti-symmetric matrix is also anti-symmetric. We have,
\begin{align}
A^i_l &= M^i_j(B^{-1})^j_l + B^i_kA^k_j(B^{-1})^j_l\\
&= (-M^j_i)(-(B^{-1})^l_j) + (-B^k_i)(-A^j_k)(-(B^{-1})^l_j)\\
&= (B^{-1})^l_jM^j_i - (B^{-1})^l_jA^j_kB^k_i\\
&= -(A^l_i) \tag{using eq.(2)}
\end{align}

This meant that the anti-symmetry of eq. (1) was manifested with the help of eq. (2). But yes, on its own it doesn't seem obvious why it would be anti-symmetric. I hope this helps clarify your doubt.